# Is it legal for a physician to refuse to give a lab collection requisition for a lab that isn't affiliated with the physician?

Tags: united-states, california, medical

I wonder the following: a physician in California, United States, gives to their patient a laboratory test requisition (e.g., a blood test) that is only valid in a lab affiliated with the physician. The patient asks for a laboratory test requisition for a different blood test center and the physician refuses. Is such a refusal legal?

Comment: The physician is free to contract with anyone. As is the patient. The patient can see another doctor.

Comment: #Trish A requisition is not a contract, however. In the US, a physician normally has no contract with the lab doing tests, which is why they bill the patient (or the patient's insurance) directly and separately.